# UI Router reroute AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to reroute all URLs pointing to /profiles/1/view to /profiles/1/edit:

```
/profiles/1/view/account   -> /profiles/1/edit/account
/profiles/1/view/messages  -> /profiles/1/edit/messages
/profiles/1/view/settings  -> /profiles/1/edit/settings
```

Can I do something like below where the * at the end of the source means match anything. For the destination, I want to paste whatever * holds to be the value of the corresponding * at the end.

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/profiles/view/{profile_id:[0-9]{0,4}}/*', '/profiles/edit/{profile_id:[0-9]{0,4}}/*');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UI Router docs

> '/files/{path:.*}' - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and
>   captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
>   '/files/*path' - Ditto. Special syntax for catch all.

With that in mind, have you tried:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/profiles/view/{profile_id:[0-9]{0,4}}/*extra', '/profiles/edit/{profile_id:[0-9]{0,4}}/*extra');
```